# JSF Session Management

Tags: java, web-applications, jsf

Hi I am making a application Student Information System.
I am using JSF. I have problem in session management. 
My requirement is

1. Admin Logs in
2. Admin See the page where he can search Students with different criteria
   like first name, last name, class , DOB etc.
   once he clicks on Search Button   A datatable is populated in the same page
   Having details like

   **Roll_No    First_Name   Last_Name   DOB**

Here Roll_No column  is Command Link On clicking of any roll no it call a backing function
which obtains More Details about that particular student and shows in a different page

In  next page where I am showing more detail of student. Admin edit some fields and save it and goes back to previous page.

It is working Perfectly fine When StudentBean is in SESSION Scope,
but I don't want to use Session scope I want to use Request scope.
because if there are 1000 Admin working at same time then performance will be effected badely.

Is this is a problem with jsf or my design issue

Thanks All

Comment: Just put the bean in request scope. If this leads to problems, then you should elaborate about exactly those problems in your question instead of asking a a too broad question which basically boils down to "I don't want to keep my beans in session all the time, what should I do?" and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

You can always pass parameter in request like `editStudent.jsf?studId=123` no need to take this data in session

**Also See**

- [Communication in JSF, from BalusC](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html)

Comment: This one might also be relevant: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html. It describes using datatables with a request scoped bean.